# Can't implement "oninitdialog" with class wizard using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, wizard

Can't implement "oninitdialog" with class wizard in my c++ project.  Using vs2012 (just installed) on a fairly new (3 mos old) computer running windows 7.  The wizard generates the following in my .cpp file:

```
BOOL cdlg1::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

#5312

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
#5313

#5312

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
#5313
    // TODO:  Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
#5313
    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
#5313
    // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Kind of looks like i may not be accessing some sort of source library.  I will probably try re-installing the software, but any other suggestions?